# Как добавить установленные .egg во встроенный Python?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, embedded

Встраиваю Python в  С++ через pythonqt или pyotherside. Сначала было

```
sys.path == ['/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload']
```

*site-packages* добавил.

```
import sys,site

for s in site.getsitepackages(): sys.path.append(s)
sys.path.append(site.getusersitepackages())
```

Но как добавить .egg?

```
['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/eri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/home/eri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/onvif-0.2.0-py3.8.egg', '/home/eri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sslkeylog-0.2.0-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg', '/home/eri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyTeliumManager-2.3.0-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg', '/home/eri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hexdump-3.3-py3.8.egg', '/home/eri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/payment_card_identifier-0.1.2-py3.8.egg', '/home/eri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pycountry-19.8.18-py3.8.egg', '/home/eri/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyserial-3.4-py3.8.egg', '/home/eri/Projects/2020/qtpyvcp', '/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```

Comment: Возможно надо добавлять оригинальные пакеты также, как и zip файлы.

Comment: Я линкую к системному питону. Но вот /bin/python3 видит яйца, а /lib/libpython3 видит только стандарт. Вопрос больше в том чтобы там такого запустить чтоб сторонние либы вписались как у интерпретатора.